# retrieve an emitted certificate from the CSR

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, ca

In the context of a Certificate Authority, I am trying to retrieve a valid live certificate (if any) from the the CA `index.txt` in order to revoke it prior to renew it from the initial CSR.

In my `index.txt` the line I am looking is

```
V       200605120159Z           D486D9E32C4DE4BA        unknown /C=LU/ST=Luxembourg/L=Luxembourg/O=My Org/OU=My Unit/CN=myhost.fqdn/emailAddress=ca@initech.com
```

I can get the Subject in the CSR with

```
openssl req -noout -subject -in sub/csr/myhost.csr.pem
```

That gets

```
subject=C = LU, ST = Luxembourg, L = Luxembourg, O = My Org, OU = My Unit, emailAddress = ca@initech.com, CN = myhost.fqdn
```

I can translate it with `sed`

```
openssl req -noout -subject -in sub/csr/myhost.csr.pem \
| sed -e 's/subject=/\//' -e 's/ = /=/g' -e 's/, /\//g'
```

But the result

```
/C=LU/ST=Luxembourg/L=Luxembourg/O=My Org/OU=My Unit/emailAddress=ca@initech.com/CN=myhost.fqdn
```

does not match the line in `index.txt` as the fields are not in the same order.

Is it possible to have the subject of a certificate and the one of a CSR in a comparable way?

Comment: Generally issuing a new cert doesn't revoke the old one, because it creates an operational race condition where the subject has to get the new cert fully in the field before the CRL (or OCSP source) gets updated. On a delay is reasonable (GoDaddy CA has a 72 hour lag), though harder than simply leaving it up to the client to initiate revocation (or not, and just wait for expiry).

Comment: @bartonjs: yes it makes sense, because on a revocation I regenerate the CRL in the same step. Thus a server could be untrusted by a client (internal infrastructure) during some time until the new certificate setup. My question is useless :o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix the order of fields in the CSR, you could try using `awk`:

```
openssl req -noout -subject -in sub/csr/myhost.csr.pem  | awk -F', ' -v OFS='/' '{sub(/^subject=/,"");gsub(" = ","=");print $1,$2,$4,$5,$7,$6}'
```

`-F', '` sets the input field separator and `-v OFS='/'` sets the output field separator.

The first `sub` command removes the `subject=` string, and the second command `gsub` squeezes the spaces around the `=` character.

Then the line is printed. Note the inversion of the 6th and 7th field.

---

But it is better to fix the order of the subject fields according to the openssl configuration file `openssl.cnf` (often located in `/etc/ssl` or `/usr/ssl`) in the `[ req_distinguished_name ]` section.

Comment: Seems OK in this specific case, but I have no guarantee on the content of future CSRs that could contain additional fields in their subjects and how they will be stored in the index.

Comment: @Seki If not overridden by command line, the order of subject field are in the order specified in the file `openssl.cnf`.

Comment: Bingo! You gave me enlightment about why the fields were not in the same order: for some reason the CSR were made with a script with a different (inlined) configuration where the `distinguished_name` definition differs from the CA's `openssl.cnf`. Thank you!